# FZF - Combine Buffers and Files

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, fzf

I'm trying to list all the files in the buffers and files without duplicates. That way, if I don't have a particular file in my list of MRU buffers, I can simply fetch the file. How do you get this to work?

Comment: Why not just use `:Buffers` and `:Files` separately? Bind to `\b`, `\f`. (Personally, I have them bound to `Tab` and `,`.)

Comment: You might enjoy a look through the [examples](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/wiki/Examples-(vim)).

Comment: I understand. But it looks like the MRU buffer helpers are private, and I may have to create a new file of the list from Files. I was wondering if there's a better way.